# Global variable not changing after function is called

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm working on a side project and admittedly I'm not very experienced with Python or coding in general but I'm trying to make a card app. I'm unable to get a global variable to change after I call a function

If I give the same suit it prints true within the function but not outside. I read online that putting global first would fix this but it hasn't. Any help is appreciated.

```
class Hand:
    people = 0
    hand = []
    suited = False
    def deal():
        global people
        global hand
        global suited
        num_1 = input("What is your first card?: ")
        suit_1 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        num_2 = input("What is your second card?: ")
        suit_2 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        people = input("How many people at the table?: ")
        card_1 = [num_1,suit_1]
        card_2 = [num_2,suit_2]
        if card_1[0] > card_2[0]:
            hand = [card_1, card_2]
        else:
            hand = [card_2, card_1]
        if card_1[1] == card_2[1]:
            suited = True
        else:
            suited = False
        print(suited)
    deal()
    print(suited)
```

I'm expecting it to change the value of suited to True after I input the same suits.

Comment: Have you tried moving those variable outside of the class?

Comment: Yeah but then I get an undefined NameError when I try to import the class and call the function elsewhere.

Comment: Then how about setting those variables as class properties? You know, using `self`

Comment: Also if you still want to use those variables as global, you need to import them as well as the class `Hand`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried using self but the problem I found was that I would need the input for suited -- etc to create an object but I won't know those values until I call the function deal

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are inside the class. Try moving them outside the class:

```py
people = 0
hand = []
suited = False

class Hand:
    def deal():
        global people
        global hand
        global suited
        num_1 = input("What is your first card?: ")
        suit_1 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        num_2 = input("What is your second card?: ")
        suit_2 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        people = input("How many people at the table?: ")
        card_1 = [num_1,suit_1]
        card_2 = [num_2,suit_2]
        if card_1[0] > card_2[0]:
            hand = [card_1, card_2]
        else:
            hand = [card_2, card_1]
        if card_1[1] == card_2[1]:
            suited = True
        else:
            suited = False
        print(f"suited: {suited}")
    deal()
    print(f"suited: {suited}")
print(f"suited: {suited}")
```

```
(py36) [~]$ python3 card_deal.py
What is your first card?: K
What is your suit?: H
What is your second card?: A
What is your suit?: H
How many people at the table?: 7
suited: True
suited: True
suited: True
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why are you using `class`. You can use Functions and global variables to make it work like following code.,

```
people = 0
hand = []
suited = False

def deal():
    # You can put your global variables in one line
    global people, hand, suited
    num_1 = input("What is your first card?: ")
    suit_1 = input("What is your suit?: ")
    num_2 = input("What is your second card?: ")
    suit_2 = input("What is your suit?: ")
    people = input("How many people at the table?: ")
    card_1 = [num_1,suit_1]
    card_2 = [num_2,suit_2]
    if card_1[0] > card_2[0]:
        hand = [card_1, card_2]
    else:
        hand = [card_2, card_1]
    if card_1[1] == card_2[1]:
        suited = True
    else:
        suited = False
    print(suited)

deal()
print(suited)
```

Output will be like below,

```
What is your first card?: K
What is your suit?: H
What is your second card?: A
What is your suit?: H
How many people at the table?: 7
suited: True
suited: True
```

But however you are trying to doing this in using **Class**. Try following code. It is using static methods and class-variables. But if you are new to python and if you have no idea about **OOP** I recommend you to follow above **Functional Code**

```
class Hand():
    # Variables which are belongs to Hand class
    # You can access them use 'Hand.<var>'
    # As Example : 'Hand.people'
    people = 0
    hand = []
    suited = False

    @staticmethod
    def deal():
        # num_1, suit_1, num_2, suit_2, card_1, card_2 are the variables
        # which are belangs to 'deal' method

        num_1 = input("What is your first card?: ")
        suit_1 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        num_2 = input("What is your second card?: ")
        suit_2 = input("What is your suit?: ")

        Hand.people = input("How many people at the table?: ")
        card_1 = [num_1,suit_1]
        card_2 = [num_2,suit_2]
        if card_1[0] > card_2[0]:
            Hand.hand = [card_1, card_2]
        else:
            Hand.hand = [card_2, card_1]
        if card_1[1] == card_2[1]:
            Hand.suited = True
        else:
            Hand.suited = False

Hand.deal()
print(Hand.people)
print(Hand.hand)
print(Hand.suited)
```

Output is something like this,

```
What is your first card?: K
What is your suit?: H
What is your second card?: A
What is your suit?: H
How many people at the table?: 7
7
[['K', 'H'], ['A', 'H']]
True
```

In **Hand Class**,
We use `hand`, `suited`, `people` variables are class variables and `deal` method is static method. Which are belongs to **Hand Class**.

Check out following resources,
[Python3 DOCS about class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
[realpython.com tutorial about static methods](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use global variables inside the class for that you can simply assign a property to the class.

```
class Hand:
    people = 0
    hand = []
    suited = False

    @classmethod
    def deal(cls):
        num_1 = input("What is your first card?: ")
        suit_1 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        num_2 = input("What is your second card?: ")
        suit_2 = input("What is your suit?: ")
        cls.people = input("How many people at the table?: ")
        card_1 = [num_1,suit_1]
        card_2 = [num_2,suit_2]
        if card_1[0] > card_2[0]:
            cls.hand = [card_1, card_2]
        else:
            cls.hand = [card_2, card_1]
        if card_1[1] == card_2[1]:
            cls.suited = True
        else:
            cls.suited = False



def main():
    h = Hand()
    h.deal()
    print(h.suited)
    print(h.people)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output for the same suit:

```
What is your first card?: 11
What is your suit?: 5
What is your second card?: 15
What is your suit?: 5
How many people at the table?: 5
True
5
```